# Output Buffering - Everything between wp_head and wp_print_footer_scripts?

Tags: php, the-content

What is the best way to use "Output Buffering" on the frontend? In my case, I need to apply some regex rules to the content generated by a theme with a page builder.

So it is not possible to edit the code with the filter `the_content`, because there everything is still available as shortcode. But I need to work with the code, which is generated when WordPress passes it through its hooks.

It looks as if it is easiest to buffer everything between `wp_head` and `wp_print_footer_scripts`:

```
public function __construct()
{

    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'start') );
    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', array( $this, 'end') );

} // end constructor

public function start() { ob_start( array( $this, 'callback' ) ); } // end start

public function end() { ob_end_flush(); } // end end

public function callback( $buffer )
{

    // do some stuff

    return $buffer;

} // end callback
```

But I have read in several places that it can lead to undesirable side effects..

Since it may also be applied to other people, I would like to know whether this can be used in the way, or whether there is perhaps a better way?

Comment: I've used this answer from kfriend (second answer, not the accepted answer) on a live multisite with paying customers - and so far it works perfectly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output

Comment: I have seen the answer from kfriend before. However, it does not work with my caching plugin. If I use kfriend's solution, no cached files are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to modify content to be output by `the_content()` but after the shortcodes have been applied, there is a much simpler approach. Shortcodes are filtered in `the_content` with priority 11 as can be seen in [default-filters.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L447):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 ); // AFTER wpautop()
```

So just write a filter function and hook it with a higher value for priority, so the content passes through it after shortcodes have been replaced.

```
public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'wpse_253803_filter' ), 20 );
}
public function wpse_253803_filter( $content ) {
    //do some stuff
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how to filter the content from the footer, sidebar, etc. in this manner?

Comment: This anwer only works if the corresponding output is passed through a filter, like `the_content`. The output of sidebars etc. is not filtered, so my approach won't work there. I just added this answer as a simpler aleternative with less side effects, as from your question it seemed possibly enough to work on `the_content`.

Answer (score 0):

When I use [output buffering](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), I hook onto [`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) since this ensures that my regex applies to the content after everything loads.

> *This action hook is fired once WordPress, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.*

Here's a template to work with when using output buffering:

```
<?php

class WPSE_253803 {
    public function __construct() {
        # Remove HTTP and HTTPS protocols
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'output_buffering' ), PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );
    }

    public function output_buffering() {
        # Enable output buffering
        ob_start( function( $content ) {
            # Enter code here...
            return $content;
        } );
    }
}
# Instantiate the class
new WPSE_253803();
```